How to scrape data from a website using JavaScript when elements lack specific identifiers?
I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage using JavaScript, but I'm encountering difficulties because the elements I need to extract don't have specific classes or IDs that I can use as selectors.
I'm working on a Chrome extension to extract car details from a website (Otomoto). The problem is that the HTML structure of the page doesn't include unique identifiers (classes or IDs) for the elements containing the data I need. Here's an example of the HTML structure:
<div data-testid="advert-details-item" class="ooa-162vy3d e18eslyg3">
    <p class="e18eslyg4 ooa-12b2ph5">Marka pojazdu</p>
    <div class="e1kfpccp0 ooa-1pe3502">Lexus</div>
</div>
<div data-testid="advert-details-item" class="ooa-162vy3d e18eslyg3">
    <p class="e18eslyg4 ooa-12b2ph5">Model pojazdu</p>
    <div class="e1kfpccp0 ooa-1pe3502">RX</div>
</div>
<!-- More similar blocks -->

Here's the JavaScript code I'm using:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.text === 'report_back') {
        let data = {};
        data.url = window.location.toString();

        try {
            let priceElement = document.querySelector('.offer-price__number');
            if (priceElement) {
                let priceText = priceElement.innerText;
                let numb = priceText.match(/\d+/g).join("");
                data.cena = numb;
            } else {
                data.cena = 'N/A';
            }

            let currencyElement = document.querySelector('.offer-price__currency');
            if (currencyElement) {
                data.waluta = currencyElement.innerText.trim();
            } else {
                data.waluta = 'N/A';
            }

            let params = [];
            let elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="advert-details-item"]');
            for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                let nameElement = elements[i].querySelector('p[class*="ooa-12b2ph5"]');
                let valueElement = elements[i].querySelector('div[class*="ooa-1pe3502"]');
                if (nameElement && valueElement) {
                    let name = nameElement.innerText.trim();
                    let value = valueElement.innerText.trim();
                    params.push({ 'name': name, 'value': value });
                }
            }

            params.forEach(param => {
                if (param.name.includes('Marka pojazdu')) data.marka = param.value;
                if (param.name.includes('Model pojazdu')) data.model = param.value;
                // Add more conditions as needed
            });

            let fieldsOrder = ['cena', 'waluta', 'marka', 'model', 'url'];
            let orderedRow = {};
            fieldsOrder.forEach(field => orderedRow[field] = data[field]);

            sendResponse(JSON.stringify(orderedRow));
        } catch (error) {
            sendResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: error.message }));
        }
    }
});


Issues:
The elements I need to extract don't have unique identifiers.
The current selectors don't always work, resulting in undefined values for some parameters.

Use :scope>p and :scope>div as selectors, no need to specify the class.

You need to show an example of somehting that doesn't work, not something that does work.
